# Adding a column in Flink table

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to add a new column to a flink table in Java

```
Table table = tEnv.sqlQuery(query.getQuery());
table = table.addColumns($("NewColumn"));
```

but I'm running into this `ValidationException`:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot resolve field [NewColumn], input field list:[ExistingColumn1, ExistingColumn2, ...].
```

I saw a similar example in the [flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#addcolumns), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I tried running the code in the debugger and it seems to be failing in the [`resolve`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/expressions/resolver/ExpressionResolver.html#:%7E:text=builder%20for%20resolver-,resolve,resolved%20list%20of%20expression,-resolveExpanding) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to add an existing column "NewColumn" as a new column to table!
As this column does not exit yet it says, Cannot resolve field [NewColumn], input field list. Take a look at example from documents. Here the column "c" already exists in the table.

```
Table result = orders.addOrReplaceColumns(concat($("c"), "sunny").as("desc"));
```

You should give an expression. and then can use .as() for column name.

```
Table addColumns(Expression... fields);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't realize that `NewColumn` had to be an existing column from the documentation.